# Skipping exceptions when using map in Haskell

Tags: haskell, error-handling, dictionary

I have the following code to return the length of a cycle in a string:

```
module Main where
import Data.List

detec ys n | 2*n > (length ys) = error "no cycle"
           | t == h = (2*n - n)
           | otherwise = detec ys (n+1)
            where
                t = ys !! n
                h = if n == 0 then ys !! 1 else  ys !! (n*2)
f x = detec (show x) 0
answer = map f [1/x|x<-[1..100]]
```

But what I don't know how to do is make it ignore the `"no cycle"` exception so that the list produced only contains the lengths of the strings which are cyclic.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please don't use `error` to implement logic where the "erroneous" result is expected to occur.

Instead, why not return `Maybe n` instead of just `n`, then [use `catMaybes`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-Maybe.html#v%3AcatMaybes) to filter out the `Nothing`s?

The changes are easy enough:

```
module Main where
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

detec ys n | 2*n > (length ys) = Nothing
           | t == h = Just (2*n - n)
           | otherwise = detec ys (n+1)
            where
                t = ys !! n
                h = if n == 0 then ys !! 1 else  ys !! (n*2)

f x = detec (show x) 0
answer = catMaybes $ map f [1/x|x<-[1..100]]
```

By the way, you're indexing past the end of the list; perhaps you meant to check `2*n + 1 > length ys`? Drifting slightly off topic, I'd like to mention that `!!` and `length` are, for the most part, both inefficient and non-idiomatic when applied to lists, especially in an iterating construct like this. The list type is basically a *cons cell list*, which is an intrinsically recursive data structure, and is emphatically *not* an array. Ideally you should avoid doing anything with a list that can't be easily expressed with pattern matching, e.g., `f (x:xs) = ...`.

Comment: +1 for discouraging `error`. Note that it isn't even possible to check against the `_|_` it returns! With an evaluated error, the whole program returns undefined.

Comment: +1 for the same, as well as discouraging array indexing, although I would have preferred it if you pointed out that OP's algorithm is faulty to begin with. Well, since you didn't, I did...

Comment: `catMaybes . map == mapMaybe`

Comment: Actually, you can catch "error" (and pattern-match failures) in IO.  But you don't want to ever get to that point; it's not an exception, it's a bug.

Answer (score 5):

Are you working on [Project Euler #26](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=26)?

Just because a certain digit repeats, doesn't mean you've found a cycle: for example, in 334/999=0.334334334…, the cycle isn't (3), it is (334).  Also, it unwise to depend on floating point computation to give you enough accurate digits: the solution to #26 definitely goes beyond what floating-point will give you.

In any case, there are easier ways to find cycles.  This keeps a list of previously-seen elements as it walks down the list, and returns when it finds that the current element has already been seen.

```
findCycle :: Eq a => [a] -> Int
findCycle = findCycle' [] where
    findCycle' _ [] = 0
    findCycle' k (x:xs) = maybe (findCycle' (x:k) xs) succ $ elemIndex x k
```

Your [tortoise and hare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) algorithm is incomplete: it may not always find the smallest cycle.  That flaw is corrected here.

```
findCycle :: Eq a => [a] -> Int
findCycle xs = findCycle' xs (tail xs) where
    findCycle' (x:xs) (y:_:ys)
      | x == y = fromJust (elemIndex x xs) + 1
      | otherwise = findCycle' xs ys
```

This assumes that it'll never run off the end of the list.  If you implement your own decimal expansion, you can easily ensure that is true.

Answer (score 3):

You might use [`catch`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Control-Exception.html#5) from Control.Exception as in

```
import Prelude hiding (catch)
import Control.Exception

main = do
  print answer `catch` errorMessage
  where
    errorMessage :: SomeException -> IO ()
    errorMessage = putStrLn . ("error: " ++) . show
```

Catching `SomeException` is sloppy, and the output is messy:

```
[error: No cycle
```

It got partway through printing an array but ran into the exception. Not very nice.

Another answer has covered the fine approach of using the `Maybe` monad for representing computations that can fail. An even more general approach is `MonadError`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Error

detec2 :: (MonadError String m, Eq a) => [a] -> Int -> m Int
detec2 ys n | 2*n >= (length ys) = throwError "No cycle"
            | t == h = return (2*n - n)
            | otherwise = detec2 ys (n+1)
             where
                 t = ys !! n
                 h = if n == 0 then ys !! 1 else  ys !! (n*2)
```

(Notice this also fixes the bug in your first guard that allows `!!` to throw exceptions.)

This permits similar but more flexible use, for example:

```
answer2 = f2 <$> [1/x | x <- [1..100]]

f2 x = detec2 (show x) 0

main = do
  forM_ answer2 $
    \x -> case x of
            Left msg -> putStrLn $ "error: " ++ msg
            Right x  -> print x
```

Now the first few lines of the output are

```
error: No cycle
error: No cycle
2
error: No cycle
error: No cycle
3
6
error: No cycle
2
```

Keep in mind this is still a pure function: you don't have to run it inside `IO`. To ignore the no-cycle errors, you might use

```
cycles :: [Int]
cycles = [x | Right x <- answer2]
```

If you don't care about errors messages at all, then don't generate them. A natural way to do this is with lists where you return the empty list for no cycles and condense the result with `concatMap`:

```
detec3 :: (Show a) => a -> [Int]
detec3 x = go 0
  where go :: Int -> [Int]
        go n
          | 2*n >= len = []
          |     t == h = [2*n - n]
          |  otherwise = go (n+1)
          where t = ys !! n
                h | n == 0    = ys !! 1
                  | otherwise = ys !! (n*2)
                len = length ys
                ys = show x

main = do
  print $ concatMap (detec3 . recip) [1..100]
```

Finally, you may be interested in reading [8 ways to report errors in Haskell](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors).

Comment: Clarifying the difference between approaches, note that `Maybe` is also a monad. `MonadError` is the more general approach by virtue of allowing you to attach error messages; if you don't care about error messages, there's not much practical difference, and both can be written either in a "direct" style or using `do` notation.